# Can I create or edit XLTM files using EPPlus?

Tags: epplus

I want to create, open or edit a `.xltm` file using EPPlus.

If I try to open it, it is opening. 
But when I edit it or copy paste formulas from that `.xltm` file to another `.xltm` file, it is not opening any more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have added some formatting to your question. We have also decided to remove "Thanks in advance" statements, since they are not helpful to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not possible in 2013 [according to this discussion](https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/429948) and [this issue post](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14826). You might want to use [OpenXml](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).

Comment: Means using EPPlus I cant do it?

Comment: And I need to use Mircosoft OpenXml?

Comment: @PrasadJoshi: Well, perhaps there are other (e.g. commercial) solutions available, so you don't "need" to use OpenXml. But as far as I can find out, EPPlus might open MLSM files but it's not guaranteed to keep the macros intact.